# Blank icon on system tray

Tags: java, trayicon

I'm trying to add an icon to the system tray, however, when I run the application the icon is blank.

My project structure is like this:

```
root/
  libs/
    ...
  src/
    com/
      projname/
        logic/
          ...
        ui/
          MyClass.java
          ...
  res/
    icon.png
```

I'm trying to add the icon inside MyClass.java, like so:

```
private void addToSystemTray() throws AWTException {

    if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        return;
    }

    // get the SystemTray instance
    SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

    // load an image
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("icon.png"));

    // construct tray icon
    TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "My Project");

    // add the tray image
    tray.add(trayIcon);
}
```

I marked the res/ folder as *Resources Root* on IntelliJ, and I also built the `.jar` to check if the icon was being added to it - and it is.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Image image = new ImageIcon(MyClass.class.getResource("/icon.png")).getImage();`

Comment: @JoopEggen That didn't fix it - same problem.

Comment: Yes, you _did_ use the javadoc example. `trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);` maybe.

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks, that fixed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably your image is larger than the tray icon size and gets cropped. That's why you see the icon as blank. So you have to set,
`trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);`

JavaDoc:

> public void **setImageAutoSize**(boolean autosize)
>
> Sets the auto-size property. Auto-size determines whether the tray
>   image is automatically sized to fit the space allocated for the image
>   on the tray. By **default**, the auto-size property is set to **false**.
>
> If auto-size is false, and the image size doesn't match the tray icon
>   space, the image is painted as-is inside that space — if larger than
>   the allocated space, it will be **cropped**.
>
> If auto-size is **true**, the image is **stretched or shrunk** to **fit** the tray
>   icon space.